# Можно ли сделать адаптивную таблицу с фиксированной шапкой на языке C?

Tags: c

К примеру, чтобы определенное значение подстраивалось под определенной блок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выводит значения в поле с определённой шириной.

Comment: [Можно](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Comment: @EOF С определенной шириной не получается: я ввожу разные значения для a и b (таблица смещается вправо).

Comment: @Kodarak, ну вы же не прочитали мануал к функции. Там есть выравнивание.

Comment: @mik.ov Действительно, спасибо.